# Can I use PropertyChanged and LostFocus together?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Below is a part of my View code in WPF MVVM structure.

```
<TextBox Name="VehicalNo_Text" Height="23" Width="80" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding VehicleNo, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
...                                   
<TextBlock Name="Preview" Text="{Binding EditText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
...
```

I came across a situation where I need to use these both triggers simultaneously.

i.e.

When I update anything in TextBox, I need to show it immediately in my Preview TextBlock. (In ViewModel EditText comes indirectly from VehicleNo itself...), which is already implemented as you can see in code.

And now what I need is when TextBox loose the focus, I need to validate on text.

Is it possible somehow to use this both properties simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

`UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` in TextBlock has no effect

however you can try this way

```
<TextBox Name="VehicalNo_Text" Height="23" Width="80" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
         Text="{Binding VehicleNo, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" 
         HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
...                                   
<TextBlock Name="Preview" Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=VehicalNo_Text}"/>
```

in above sample we bind the Text property of preview TextBlock to the Text property of TextBox instead of view model property

this will enable you to see a live preview while keeping view model update on lost focus only.

**Edit**

in order to validate the property you can apply validation rule on TextBox's binding

eg

```
<TextBox Name="VehicalNo_Text">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="VehicleNo" UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <ExceptionValidationRule />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

you can replace ExceptionValidationRule or add with your own rules.

secondly instead of heaving a calculated property you may perhaps use a converter to display the preview based on VehicleNo's value

eg

```
<TextBlock Name="Preview" Text="{Binding Text, ElementName=VehicalNo_Text, Converter={StaticResource VehicalNoConverter}}"/>
```

Comment: As I said, that property is already working for me as I have bonded EditText with VehicleNo in ViewModel.
I am worried about just my problem of simultaneously setting both.

Comment: Also its my requirement of software to do like that because many such TextBoxes are connected to this Preview.

Comment: It seems like you didn't understand my question yet.

Comment: from what I can see, you are looking forward to keep the binding intact while adding a validation on property value when the TextBox loses focus. to achieve that you may need to adjust the code behind to keep the original values (as the current value will be overwritten) and compare them when textbox looses focus and revert if necessary. I am suggesting you an approach which does not require you to keep the original value while keeping the desired behavior.

Comment: Sry I have some requirements of my software and I can't change it. What I need is just one important thing: "How to access UpdateProperty and LostFocus both on the same element i.e. TextBox here."

Comment: To be precise both triggers are not applicable at the same time as their behavior is contradictory. You may have to implement your own mechanism for the same.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to set both modes (e.g. PropertyChanged|LostFocus) in xaml, but there is workaround. Assume you have Slider and you want to react in your ViewModel on Value changed and on focus lost event (actually I use LostMouseCapture event)

```
<Slider Value="{Binding NewValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <b:Interaction.Triggers>
        <b:EventTrigger EventName="LostMouseCapture">
            <b:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SliderLostFocusCommand}"/>
        </b:EventTrigger>
    </b:Interaction.Triggers>
</Slider>
```

You have to also include this namespaces in your xaml

```
xmlns:b="clr-amespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
```